# addEventListener and attachevent type mismatch on IE11.0

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11, html-select

Hi i accounter some problem with javascript on DOM.

I am using IE v11.0

I have a page consist of a few buttons, upload file and select box

upon loading, I accounter an error stated that Type mismatch.

i have a select box which act nothing but just a few option

```
<select id="myOption">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I have a java script which wil do something to an image if it select

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("myOption").attachEvent("onclick", imgChange());

    function imgChange(){
        // declare some variaables and change some element.

     }
</script>
```

Upon running, in the console, it will say type mismatch on

```
document.getElementById("myOption").attachEvent("onclick", imgChange());
```

I have change it to "addEventListener("onclick, imgChange());" however it does the same as well..

Help be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The event name is "click", not "onclick", and you should pass a reference to the function, not call the function so `addEventListener("click", imgChange)`. See [*MDN EventTarget.addEventListener*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). *attachEvent* is seriously *passe*. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your script like below:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("myOption").attachEvent("click", imgChange);

    function imgChange(){
    // declare some variables and change some element.

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You can change `attachEvent` to `addEventListener`